# How to draw an undefined amount of random points in a circle using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry, point

**So I have tried plotting points on a circle and did pretty good, but now I'm at a roadblock.**

**I have used an algorithm that generates a pair of random numbers which have a linear probability line, so the closer you get to the max value going from 0 it has the greater chance to choose that point**

(in my case the max value is +-1 [the circle's diameter is 2]).

**Now I want to use that algorithm to generate X amount of pairs which I can use to plot the points all at once, how do I do that?**

(The random number algorithm comes from this Youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4y_nmpv-9lI great video BTW)

my code:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def sum_dist():
    theta = random.random() * 2 * math.pi
    r = random.random() + random.random()
    if r >= 1:
        r = 2 - r
    if r <= -1:
        r = 2 + r
    #The random number algorithm
    print((r * math.cos(theta), r * math.sin(theta)))
    #This is to check if the numbers generated and what are they
    x = r * math.cos(theta)
    y = r * math.sin(theta)

    circle1 = plt.Circle((0, 0), 1, color='blue', fill = False)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    ax.add_patch(circle1)

    plt.plot([x], [y], 'ro')
    #plotting a single point in the circle
    plt.plot([0], [0], 'ro')
    #This is to Identify the center of the circle 
    plt.axis([0, 0, 0, 0])
    plt.show()

    plt.show()

sum_dist()
```

Comment: I admittedly didn't watch the video, but if you are looking for evenly spaced dots throughout your circle, noting that the area in the circle follows `r**2`, you can also use that fact to scale your random number accordingly. Doing a histogram of 10,000 samples of `r` and comparing by eye, I am pretty sure `r = math.sqrt(random.random())`, gets the same result.

Comment: I do remember that was mention in the video (r = math.sqrt(random.random()) but I didn't understand that algorithm so I didn't use it.

Comment: Fair enough! Always better to understand your code. :) Not sure if you are familiar with cumulative distributions and calculus, but the area of a smaller circle of radius `r1` relative to a larger circle of radius `r2 >=r 1` is `r1**2 / r2**2`, or `(r1 / r2)**2`. This is also the cumulative distribution of points in the circle of radius `r2` that are also in the smaller circle of radius `r1`. The probability distribution (what you want) is the derivative of the cumulative distribution, so for `r2 = 1` and `r1 = r` where `r <= 1` is `d/dr (r**2) = 2r`.

Comment: No... I don't know those I only recently started learning to code and I'm just in 9th grade (no calculus for us ): )  while I have a bit more understanding and knowledge of math (we didn't learn about cos, sin and tan I taught those my self).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want a scatter plot, like this:

```
import math
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def sum_dist():

    x = []
    y = []
    for _ in range(100):
        theta = random.random() * 2 * math.pi
#        r = random.random()
        r = random.random() + random.random()
        if r >= 1:
            r = 2 - r
# This can't happen.
#        if r <= -1:
#            r = 2 + r
        x.append( r * math.cos(theta) )
        y.append( r * math.sin(theta) )


    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_aspect( 1 )
    ax.add_artist( plt.Circle((0, 0), 1, ec='blue', fill = False) )
    ax.axhline(y=0)
    ax.axvline(x=0)
    plt.axis( [-1,1,-1,1] )
    plt.scatter(x, y, marker='o')
    plt.plot([0], [0], 'ro')
    plt.show()

sum_dist()
```

It's worth pointing out that `numpy` could do that all inline, without using a loop.  It's also worth pointing out that adding two random numbers together does not make them more random.  `random.random() * 2` would be exactly the same.

All the manipulations of `r` don't make sense.  You generate a random number from 0 to 2, then you mirror those between 1 and 2.  Mirroring a uniform random sequence is pointless.  It's still uniform.

Comment: As a side note, adding `random.random()` a few times is not quite the same as computing `random.random()*n`. The latter gives a uniform distribution, the former will be converging with `n` to the normal distribution.

Comment: Thx,
the adding of 2 random numbers is important, remember that multiplying a number by 2 always gives an even last digit which eliminates half of all outcomes, and adding two separate random numbers always gives you a number between 0 and 1 and gives the possibility to get a number over 1 so you can mirror it by abstracting 2

Comment: Btw can you explain what you did when making the circle? this is the first time I used matplotlib so I don't understand

Comment: Concerning *"remember that multiplying a number by 2 always gives an even last digit which eliminates half of all outcomes"* is mistaken, as you are working with [floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic). Multiplying by 2 doesn't change the mantissa, it only adds one to the exponent.

Comment: If you google each of the function calls (`ax.set_aspect()`, etc.) I think you should be able to understand what each line in Tim's code does.